# How to make scroll bar start from the top in every page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

who could help me out?
In my react app, I have 3 pages
1.Homepage
2.Settings page
3.Profile page

When I scroll down in the homepage and I navigate to the profile or settings page, it displays the bottom of these next pages corresponding to where I left the scroll bar in the homepage.

How do I stop react from remembering the scroll point when I navigate.

Comment: please show code example or code sandbox so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: Are you using react router or not?

Comment: @ShameelUddin Yeah, I'm using react router.

Answer (score 2):

To scroll to the top, include `useEffect()` that will scroll the page to the top when that component loads. Include this on each page that you want to scroll to the top on load.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export const Homepage = () => {

   useEffect(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0), []);

   return (<>Hello, world!</>)

}
```

Note that the second parameter of `useEffect` can take a variable so that it runs whenever that variable changes. This could allow you to include this code on a higher-level component that watches for page changes.

```
useEffect(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0), [page]);
```

Comment: Awesome! I would play around with this!